# LOOKUP Functions in Excel

Tags: excel

What is the name of the oldest community?

- Town 1 1995
- Town 2 2003
- Town 3 1988

So I used the following formula:

```
=LOOKUP(MIN(B1:B3),B1:B3,A1:A3)
```

But **it returns N/A**, However if I were not to include Third town in the formula it would return *Town 1*.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a big fan of VLOOKUP, LOOKUP, or HLOOKUP [for various reasons](http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup.htm). May I instead suggest the following solution:

```
=INDEX(A1:A3,MATCH(MIN(B1:B3),B1:B3,0))
```